# Golang get value of typed constants

Tags: go, enums, constants

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use constants in Go for use cases like I'd use enums in other languages, but I'm struggling to use typed constants properly.

Let's say we have the following constants:

```
type Status string

const (
    Created Status = "Created"
    Completed Status = "Completed"
)
```

It looks like you can get `Status` from a string by the following:

```
status := Status(s)
```

How can you go the other way? I know that you can implement a `String` method, but what if I just want whatever the underlying value is in the core type, be it `int` or `string`? The internet is failing me...

Comment: `string(status)`, or `int(IntStatus)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

As @burak-serdar mentions, the solution is pretty simple:

```
string(status)
```

Or:

```
int(intStatus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there's a little bit of confusion but your underlying type for the constants you are creating there are strings, not integers. So using `int(Created)` is going to leave you with an `cannot convert Created (type Status) to type int` error.

If you're after an Enum and want a string value to be associated with it - you should use the Stringer interface like you suggested, simple approach would be the below:

```
type Status int

func (s Status) String() string {
    switch s {
    case 0:
        return "Created"
    case 1:
        return "Deleted"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

const (
    Created Status = iota
    Deleted
)
```

Then any time you need the string version of your Status you can call `string(Created)` or simply pass it as normal (i.e. `fmt.Println(Created)`)